# Error al actualizar 2 columnas de diferentes tablas por medio de un JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query con la que intento actualizar el nombre del usuario y el nombre del post asociado a ese usuario

```
UPDATE users
    JOIN posts ON (users.id = posts.user_id)
SET
    users.nameUser = "mas blabla",
    posts.namePost = "blabla"
WHERE users.id = 1;
```

Sin embargo me regresa el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si modifico la query y solo la dejo así entonces funciona:

```
UPDATE users
    JOIN posts ON (users.id = posts.user_id)
SET
    users.nameUser = "mas blabla"
WHERE users.id = 1;
```

No comprendo el por que del error

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He probado con valores numéricos, de otras columnas para actualizarlos y la query funciona; de este modo

```
UPDATE users
    JOIN posts ON (users.id = posts.user_id)
SET
    users.nameUser = "mas blabla",
    posts.statusPost = 1
WHERE users.id = 1;
```

Entonces por que con un valor en formato de cadena de texto falla?

Hago la aclaración, ninguno de los títulos de posts que tengo registrados coincide con el de la actualización; sin importar cual valor ponga todos los marca como duplicados

Comment: Por el error que muestras :"Duplicate entry for key namePost", la columna namePost de tu tabla posts es UNIQUE y ya tienes un registro con 'blabla', tal vez por eso no te deja actualizar la columna.

Comment: no amigo, creeme ya revise todos mis datos y no estoy colocando ninguno repetido

Comment: Tal vez puedas revisar el siguiente link : http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/duplicate_entry_for_key_error , tiene algo de similitud con el error que tienes.

Comment: ya he agregado una propuesta de solución; gracias por las recomendaciones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno respondiendo a mi pregunta, expongo lo siguiente

El error que dice

> duplicate entry ***** for posts

Es debido a que no note que tengo mas de una publicación asignada o creada por el mismo usuario, aparte de eso el campo `namePost` tiene el atributo de `UNIQUE` entonces cuando  trato de actualizar el nombre del post por medio de un `JOIN` el mismo nombre trata de asignarse a esos dos registros del mismo usuario y por ende por la condición de `UNIQUE` en el nombre de la publicación, es que sale ese error

**SOLUCIÓN**

Agregué en el `WHERE` el operador `AND` para establecer otro parámetro en la condición y que de esta manera la actualización no ocurra del modo en que lo ontentaba y daba como resultado el error

```
UPDATE users
    JOIN posts ON (users.id = posts.user_id)
SET
    users.nameUser = "mas blabla",
    posts.namePost = "blabla"
WHERE users.id = 1 AND posts.namePost = "Aire comprimido";
```

> Así por ejemplo el `UPDATE` en lugar de tratar de aplicarse a los dos
>   registros del mismo usuario, solo se aplica a uno